Measure-Theoretical Language of Statistical Mechanical Ensembles
The power set of a set $X$, denoted by $\mathscr{P}(X)$ is the set of all subsets of $X$,
$\mathscr{P}(X) = \{ A \mid A \subseteq X \}$
Let $X$ and $Y$ be nonempty sets, and let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a map.
Let $f : X \to Y$ be a map and let $A$ be a nonempty subset of $X$. The map $f|_A : A \to Y$ given by $f|_A(a) = f(a)$ is called the restriction of $f$ to $A$.
Let $f : X \to Y$ be a map and let $B$ be a nonempty subset of $Y$ such that $f(X) \subseteq B$. The map $f^{|B} : X \to B$ given by $f^{|B}(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in X$ is called the corestriction of $f$ to $B$. In particular, $f^{|B}$ is obtained by restricting the codomain of $f$ to $B$.
The image of a subset $A \subseteq X$ under $f$, denoted by $f_\rightarrow (A)$, is a subset of the codomain $Y$ consisting exactly of those elements of $Y$ that are the image of some elements of $A$ under $f$:
$f_\rightarrow (A)= \{ f(x) \mid x \in A \}\subseteq Y$
Similarly, given a map $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and a subset $B \subseteq Y$, the inverse image or preimage of $B$ under $f$ is the subset of the domain $X$ of $f$, denoted by $f^\leftarrow(B)$, consisting of those elements whose image under $f$ is in $B$:
$f^\leftarrow(B)=\{ x \in X \mid f(x) \in B \}\subseteq X$
Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y\rightarrow Z$ be maps, where $X$,$Y$, and $Z$ are nonempty sets. The composite function of $f$ and $g$ is a function $g \circ f:X \rightarrow Z$ defined by
$(\forall x \in X) \; (g \circ f)(x) = g(f(x))$
Notice that any function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ defines a function $f_\rightarrow : \mathscr{P}(X) \rightarrow \mathscr{P}(Y)$ and another function $f^\leftarrow : \mathscr{P}(Y) \rightarrow \mathscr{P}(X)$. When $g: Y \rightarrow Z$ is a function, a composite function $g \mathbin{\circ} f: X \rightarrow Z$ is defined, along with corresponding functions $(g \mathbin{\circ} f)_\rightarrow : \mathscr{P}(X) \rightarrow \mathscr{P}(Z)$ and $(g \mathbin{\circ} f)^\leftarrow : \mathscr{P}(Z) \rightarrow \mathscr{P}(X)$.
The commutative diagrams below illustrate this.

If $X$ is a set, a sigma-algebra or $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$ is a collection $\Sigma \subseteq \mathscr{P}(X)$ such that

$X \in \Sigma$
$\emptyset \in \Sigma$
$(\forall A \in \Sigma) \; X \backslash A \in \Sigma$
If $I$ is some countable indexing set and $(A_i)_{i \in I}$ is a family of elements of $\Sigma$ indexed by $I$, then

$$\bigcup_{i \in I}A_i\in \Sigma $$
A measurable space is an ordered pair $(X,\Sigma)$, where $X$ is a set and $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$. Elements of $\Sigma$ are called $\Sigma$-measurable sets (or simply measurable sets when the respective $\sigma$-algebra is clear from the context).
Suppose $(X_1,\Sigma_1)$ and $(X_2,\Sigma_2)$ are measurable spaces. Then an $\Sigma_1 /\Sigma_2$-measurable function or a $\Sigma_1 /\Sigma_2$-measurable map (usually called a measurable function or a measurable map when the context is clear) is a function $f:(X_1,\Sigma_1) \rightarrow (X_2,\Sigma_2)$ such that the inverse image of any element of $\Sigma_2$ under $f$ is $\Sigma_1$-measurable:
$$f\, \text{is $\Sigma_1 /\Sigma_2$-measurable} \Leftrightarrow (\forall B \in \Sigma_2) \, f^\leftarrow(B) \in \Sigma_1 $$
Let $X$ be a set and $\Sigma$ a $\sigma$-algebra over $X$. A set function $\mu$ from $\Sigma$ to the extended real number line $[0, \infty]$ is called a measure if the following conditions hold:

$(\forall A \in \Sigma) \; \mu(A) \geq 0$.
$\mu(\emptyset) = 0$.
Let $I$ be a countable indexing set. Then if $(A_i)_{i \in I}$ is a of pairwise disjoint sets in $\Sigma$, we have
$$\mu \left ( \bigcup_{i \in I}A_i \right )=\sum_{i \in I}\mu (A_i)$$

If at least one set $A$ has finite measure, then the requirement $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$ is met automatically due to countable additivity:
$$
\mu(A) = \mu(A \cup \emptyset) = \mu(A) + \mu(\emptyset),
$$
and therefore $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$.
An ordered tern $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ is called a measure space.
A pushforward measure or image measure is obtained by transferring (or "pushing forward") a measure from one measurable space to another using a measurable function.
Given measurable spaces $(X_1, \Sigma_1)$ and $(X_2, \Sigma_2)$, a measurable mapping $f: X_1 \to X_2$, and a measure $\mu: \Sigma_1 \to [0, +\infty]$, the pushforward of $\mu$ is defined to be the measure $\mu \circ f^\leftarrow: \Sigma_2 \to [0, +\infty]$ given by:
$$
(\forall B \in \Sigma_2)\quad (\mu \circ f^\leftarrow)(B) = \mu(f^{-1}(B))  
$$
The pushforward measure is denoted by $\mu \circ f^{\leftarrow}$, and can in some sense be thought of as the composition of $f^{\leftarrow}:\mathscr{P}(X_2) \rightarrow \mathscr{P}(X_1)$ restricted and corestricted respectively to subsets $\Sigma_2 \subseteq \mathscr{P}(X_2)$ and $\Sigma_1 \subseteq \mathscr{P}(X_1)$ (remembering that any $\sigma$-algebra on a set $X$ is a subset of the power set $\mathscr{P}(X)$ of $X$) with the measure $\mu: \Sigma_1 \to [0, +\infty]$.
Let $(X_1, \Sigma_1, \mu)$ be a measure space. A probability measure is a measure with total measure one—that is, $\mu(X) = 1$. A probability space is a measure space with a probability measure. We often denoted a probability measure by $\mathbb{P}$.
Now I change notation to more popular probability notation, denoting the sample space by $\Omega$, the event space by $\Sigma$ ($\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$), and a probability measure by $\mathbb{P}$.
Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. A random variable $X$ is a $\Sigma / \Sigma'$-measurable function from a probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mathbb{P})$ to a measurable space $(\Omega', \Sigma')$, where $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega$ and $\Sigma'$ is a $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega'$.
When the image of a random variable $X$ is finite or countably infinite, the random variable is called a discrete random variable.
When the image of a random variable $X$ is uncountably infinite (usually on an interval), then $X$ is called a continuous random variable.
Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and let $(\Omega', \Sigma')$ be a measurable space. Let $X$ be a random variable on $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mathbb{P})$ taking values in $(\Omega', \Sigma')$. Then the probability distribution of $X$, written $\mathbb{P}_X$, is the pushforward measure $\mathbb{P} \circ X^\leftarrow$ of $\mathbb{P}$ under $X$ on $\Omega'$. That is,
$$
(\forall B \in \Sigma') \quad \mathbb{P}_X(B) = (\mathbb{P} \circ X^\leftarrow)(B) = \mathbb{P}(X^{\leftarrow}(B)) 
$$
where $X^{\leftarrow}(B)$ denotes the preimage of $B$ under $X$.

A section of "Convexity in the Theory of Lattice Gases" by Robert B. Israel reads:

One of the great problems of equilibrium statistical mechanics is to show how the laws of thermodynamics arise from microscopic dynamics. The issue here is not an analysis of the approach to equilibrium of non-equilibrium states—that is another great problem and one whose solution is necessary for a full understanding of the notion of equilibrium—but of finding a definition of equilibrium state and of the associated thermodynamic functions in terms of the Hamiltonian so that the laws of thermodynamics follow. Pioneering work on this problem was done by Maxwell and Boltzmann. Their ideas were codified by Gibbs whose formulation of equilibrium statistical mechanics has persisted to this day in classical statistical mechanics and was adopted with only a few formal changes in quantum statistical mechanics, once quantum mechanics was invented.
Given a Hamiltonian system of $N$ degrees of freedom with Hamiltonian $H_N$, Gibbs defined two probability measures on phase space, the microcanonical and canonical ensembles. If, for simplicity, the phase space is assumed to be $\mathbb{R}^{2N}$, the microcanonical ensemble for a system of energy $U$ in a subset $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined by the probability measure
$$
d\mu_{\text{micro}}(U, V, N; q, p) = [Z_{\text{micro}}(U, V, N)]^{-1} \frac{1}{N!} \chi_V(q) \delta(U - H_N) d^N q \, d^N p
$$
where the normalization factor $Z_{\text{micro}}(U, V, N)$ is the microcanonical partition function
$$
Z_{\text{micro}}(U, V, N) = \frac{1}{N!} \int \delta(U - H_N) \chi_V(q) \, d^N q \, d^N p.
$$
Here
$$
d^N q = dq_1 \cdots dq_N, \quad d^N p = dp_1 \cdots dp_N
$$
$\delta$ is Dirac's delta function, and $\chi_V(q) = 0$ if $q \notin V$ while it is $= 1$ if $q \in V$. Gibbs also considered the possibility of using some other function in place of Dirac's $\delta$, say the characteristic function of an interval; in the limit of a large system these possibilities turned out to be equivalent.
The canonical ensemble for a system at temperature $T$ in a subset $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined by the probability measure
$$
d\mu_{\text{can}}(\beta, V, N; q, p) = Z_{\text{can}}(\beta, V, N)^{-1} \frac{1}{N!} \exp(-\beta H_N) \chi_V(q) d^N q \, d^N p
$$
where $\beta = (kT)^{-1}$ and the normalization factor $Z_{\text{can}}(\beta, V, N)$ is the canonical partition function
$$
Z_{\text{can}}(\beta, V, N) = \frac{1}{N!} \int \exp(-\beta H_N) \chi_V(q) \, d^N q \, d^N p.
$$
The third ensemble used by Gibbs is especially adapted to systems containing arbitrary numbers of identical particles. Then it is natural to adapt the coordinates and momenta appearing in the Hamiltonian to the particles, using $N$ as a label for the number of particles. The phase space is then $\mathbb{R}^{6N}$, and $V$ refers to a region in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Given a sequence of Hamiltonians $H_N$, $N = 1, 2, 3, \dots$, one then defines a measure on the product space $\prod_{N=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{R}^{6N}$ by
$$
d\mu_{\text{grand}}(\beta, V, \mu; q, p) = \left[Z_{\text{grand}}(\beta, V, \mu)\right]^{-1} \sum_{N=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{N!} \exp[-\beta H_N + \beta \mu n] d^{3N} q \, d^{3N} p.
$$
Here on the left-hand side $qp$ is a point of $\prod_{N=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{R}^{6N}$, i.e., a sequence $(0,0, \vec{q}_1^{(1)}, \vec{p}_1^{(1)}, \vec{q}_1^{(2)}, \vec{p}_1^{(2)}, \dots)$, and by convention $\mathbb{R}^0$ is a one-point space with measure 1. This probability measure is called the grand canonical ensemble. The parameter $\mu$ is the chemical potential. The normalization factor $Z_{\text{grand}}(\beta, V, \mu)$ is the grand canonical partition function
$$
Z_{\text{grand}}(\beta, V, \mu) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{\beta \mu n} Z_{\text{can}}(\beta, n, V).
$$

I'm a bit confused by the first equation in this passage. In general, giving an equation of the form
$$ d\mu =f\,d^N\!p\,d^N\!q, \label{1}\tag{1},$$
with $f=f(q,p)$ being a function of the variables $q=(q_1,...,q_N),p=(p_1,...,p_N)$, is something that I interpret as follows: $\mu$ is a measure on $\mathbb{R}^{2N}$ defined by
$$\mu(E)=\int_{E}f(q,p)d^N\!p\,d^N\!q, \qquad E\subset \mathbb R^{2N}.$$
However, in the equation
$$
d\mu_{\text{micro}}(U, V, N; q, p) = [Z_{\text{micro}}(U, V, N)]^{-1} \frac{1}{N!} \chi_V(q) \delta(U - H_N) d^N q \, d^N p, \label{2}\tag{2}
$$
the right hand side contains the Dirac delta, which means that "$f$" here, as in equation \eqref{1}, is not a function, but rather a measure. This is confusing: I know how to make sense of the expression \eqref{1} when $f$ is a function, but I don't know what is its mathematical meaning when $f$ itself is a measure.
Question: Can someone clarify what is going on formally in equation \eqref{2}? What does the equation mean mathematically?
A friend sent the following Wikipedia link concerning the Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem:
Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem
However, I fail to see how that is relevant in this situation.

Why closing votes without even leaving comments? The question is clear, and it’s also interesting.

I think what is going on here is a sort of abuse of notation from a mathematical perspective, although a physicist might say this is just a “different notation”. To explain this notation, I will start from the basics.

Consider the delta measure centered at zero on $\mathbb R$. If you pretend for a second that the delta is a function, you might be tempted to write the identity
$$\int_{\mathbb R}\delta(x)dx=1.\label{eq:1}\tag{1}$$
More precisely, here we are pretending that the delta measure is absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure, and that there is a density function $f$ such that (as you wrote in your answer)
$$ \int_Id\delta=\int_I f(x)dx. $$
This is of course not the case, but the formula \eqref{eq:1} is still rather immediate to understand, it is possible to give a meaning to it and generalize it in nice ways (the right keyword here is “Delta calculus”, see e.g. this paper). In other words, we can think of
$$ \delta(x)dx $$
just as a sort of fancy way of writing the measure $d\delta$, but this fancy writing has its advantages: for example, if I write
$$ \delta(x-1)dx $$
it is immediate to understand that I mean the Dirac delta measure centered at $x=1$. If I write
$$ \delta(2x)dx, $$
I can probably convince you that a reasonable definition would be $\delta/2$, since rescaling the integrand $f$ by a factor of $2$ halves the value of the integral. Less immediate, but still a natural consequence, one can make sense of a more complicated expression, like
$$ \delta(x^2-1)dx. $$
This will have to be $\delta_{-1}/2+\delta_1/2$: the reason is that $x^2-1$ equals zero precisely at $x=\pm 1$, and close to those points, the function $g(x)=x^2-1$ is approximately $g(x)\approx \pm 2(x\mp 1)$, so you can reduce the above measure to the previous two cases.
In general, you have a formula to interpret $\delta(g(x))dx$:
$$\delta(g(x))dx=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{|g’(a_i)|}\delta(x-a_i)dx,\label{eq:2}\tag{2}$$
where $(a_i)$ are the zeroes of $g$ (see the second formula in the linked paper). This reasoning can also be applied in higher dimensions with the appropriate caution: for instance, writing
$$ \delta(x^2+y^2-1)dx\,dy $$
will be a way of denoting a uniform measure supported on the unit circle in $\mathbb R^2$.

So, back to your question. In the book, the expression
$$ \delta(U-H_N)d^Npd^Nq $$
is meant to indicate a measure that is supported on the set
$$ S_U:=\{(p,q)\in \mathbb R^{2N}\,\,|\,\,H_N(p,q)=U \}. $$
With nice assumptions on $H_N$, this set will look like a $2N-1$ surface in $\mathbb R^{2N}$, or a union of such surfaces. In particular, it will generally have measure zero in $\mathbb R^{2N}$, so the measure $\delta(U-H_N)d^Npd^Nq$ will be singular w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^{2N}$.
What measure is it? A natural candidate would be the Hausdorff measure of the surface $S_U$ (it is perfectly possible that this is what the book means, but I doubt it). It turns out, though, that this is not the “right” definition. A natural definition, that matches the intuition and the rules we have discussed above, is
$$\int_A\delta(U-H_N(p,q))d^Npd^Nq = \int_{A\cap S_U} \frac{1}{|\nabla_{p,q} H_N(p,q)|} d\mathcal H^{2N-1},\label{eq:3}\tag{3}$$
where $A\subset \mathbb R^{2N}$, and $d\mathcal H^{2N-1}$ is the Hausdorff measure on $S_U$ (the surface measure). This measure makes sense when $H_N$ has non-vanishing gradient on $S_U$ (or with slightly weaker assumptions). You can notice that \eqref{eq:3} is basically a generalization of \eqref{eq:2} to higher dimensions.

Thanks a lot for this extensive answer. I was taking a look at the following article,
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00252915,
but I'm not sure if this can provide any insight into what I'm looking at.

It looks like a nice reading. But I think it is not necessary to clarify your doubt. With my answer I wanted to say that basically writing $\delta(f(x))dx$ is just a notation for a rigorously defined measure, the definition being formula (3). The only weird thing is the term "Hausdorff measure", with which you might not be familiar: it is just a way of denoting the natural surface measure on $S_U$. Feel free to ask if you have doubts. Btw, since yours is a nice question, I would suggest to edit the post and write more clearly what your doubt and your question is, so that it can be reopened.

I tried to edit the post, but people did not vote for reopening, I don't understand why.

That makes sense now. I suppose that they didn't re-open my question because I personally didn't edit it; nevertheless, I think you've actually answered my question, I just need to learn a bit more measure theory to completely alleviate my confusions.
